# Global variables???? not being set by function

Tags: javascript

Ok I've looked at a few questions and am now confused.

I have a code say:

```
var basket = null;

function loadBasket(){
    // do somesthing
    basket = "something";
    console.log(basket);
    load();
}

function load(){
    // do something with basket variable
}

loadBasket();
```

The load function seems to return null for basket even though I've set it previously in the loadBasket() function. The only thing I can think of is the order in which I've called the functions. I've got similar functions on other sites that work fine, this one doesn't though. Is it the order is there something I'm missing. Could someone please explain, if they don't mind doing so.

The console log returns whatever I have in place of "something", so why is the following function not recognising the newly changed variable.

edit:

ok i set it up because i'm not clear on callbacks and am using post requests. so real function is simular to this.

```
var basketId = readCookie('basket');

function loadBasket(){
    $.post("test.php", {"email":email}, function(data){
         if(data = 0){
             basketId = readCookie('basket');
         }
         if(data == null){
             basketId = data;
         }
         else{
             basketId = data;
             console.log(basketId);
             load();
         }
    });
}

function load()
    if(basketId == null){
        console.log(basketId);
        //do something
    }
    else{
        $.post('basket.php', {"basketId":basketId}
    }
}

pageLoad();
```

it's a little more complex but the idea is the same, iI would have though it would work, but it doesn't even though console.log shows data for basketId. In the load section it acts as if basket is null even though the other console.log shows basketId changing. Like I said I've got other functions on other pages that are the same but work.

edit 2:

other function that works:

```
var basketId = readCookie("basket");

function loadTables(){
   if(something){
       $.post("test.php", {"basketId":basketId}, function(data){
          //do something with data
       });
   }
   else{
       //do something
   }
}

function loginCheck(){
     if(something){
        $.post("test2.php", {"email":email}, function(data2){
           if(something){
                createCookie('basket', data2, 0);
                basketId = data2;
                loadTables();
           }
           else{
                return false;
           }
        });
     }
     else{
          return false;
     }
 }

 loginCheck();
```

Comment: How are you calling `load` and `loadBasket`?

Comment: sorry I'll edit the questions

Comment: You will need to show what is in your `load` function

Comment: http://jsbin.com/koxeqi/1/edit?js,console — cannot reproduce

Comment: _"The load function seems to return null for basket "_ No value appear returned from `load()` ? _"The console log returns whatever I have in place of "something", so why is the following function not recognising the newly changed variable"_ Is `console.log(basket)` called within `load()` ?, or on next line after `loadBasket()` is called ? Can create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ to demonstrate ?

Comment: @HelloWorld How would using an IIFE change results described at OP ?

Comment: @HelloWorld — As opposed to when they aren't in an IIFE and so are in the same (global) scope…

Comment: Re: The edit to the question.  Paulpro's duplicate close was correct.

Comment: @TomAlbanese Tried passing `basketId` to `load` as a parameter `load(basketId)` ?

Comment: I could do that but why doesn't this work. I mean I will try that, but on other functions that are simular it works. should I change them even though they work

Comment: @TomAlbanese Callback of `$.post()` is asynchronous . Where is `pageLoad`  defined ?

Comment: pageLoad is defined on it's own designed to load on page load. Like I said I've done similar things before and they work, surely calling the function on completion of the request means that it should now use updated basketId. What really puzzles me is why similar functions work.

Comment: I need to know this, my whole site does a similar thing of setting global variables then using them in functions. Why would this example be different. I've also got similar post requests that I don't want breaking one day.

Comment: @TomAlbanese _"Why would this example be different."_  See condition at `if(data = 0)` ? which sets `data` to `0` ? Try at `console` : `var data;  if (data = 0) {
  console.log("if", data)
} else {
  console.log("else", data)
}` . Try changing operator to `==` or `===`

Comment: nah, thats a typo. On closer inspection it is something to do with callback, I think. I have another post request that deals with data in a similar way and that isn't working either. I fixed it with parameters, but still have another function that does the same thing but was working fine. The only thing I can think of is that it uses a similar readCookie statement, but that one actually creates a cookie before calling the function. It's still in the oncompletion section it just doesn't use the data that has been retrived. I'll edit to show.

Comment: @TomAlbanese _"nah, thats a typo."_ Ok; what is actual operator used at  `if` condition ? Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce issue described at OP ?

Comment: it should be "==". I don't use jsfiddle, does it work with post requests

Comment: Yes, jsfiddle works with post requests. Entire `js` at Question could be reproduced , see http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html . Could also use http://plnkr.co

Comment: @TomAlbanese Tried reproducing _"The load function seems to return null for basket even though I've set it previously in the loadBasket() function."_ at jsfiddle ?

Comment: no i've got housework to do